# Adding Open Graph Tags for Existing FB Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working to get my existing website more tightly integrated with my existing facebook page for that web page.

In the Open Graph documentation, I see ways to put in your admin ids or your app id. However I don't see a way to put in an existing Facebook page ID.

I have run into this problem in the past and when put myself as the admin id as well as all the other open graph tags, it generated an entirely new fb page for me that I don't want or need.

So, long story short - how do I add open graph tags to associate my webpage with an existing facebook page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following meta tag:

`<meta property="fb:page_id" content="YOURPAGEID (integer)" />`

Comment: Thanks - I had this in already for insights, but since it didn't have the og:page_id property I wasn't sure if it correlated to the open graph or just insights for websites. Thanks!